# React component via custom npm package. module cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a custom npm package that will allow me to import some of my components over multiple projects. I wrote a simple package yesterday which can be found here: [demo npm package](https://github.com/rwormsbecher/customnpmpackage). It's a simple starter project that has a webpack config and a uses npx babel to transpile and copy the files to the dist and lib folder.

If I include this package into my own project it works but not as I would expect. when I use the following code:

```
import {NavBar, HelloLib} from "testprivatenprodney;
```

It gives an error "Module not found".

when I use

```
import { NavBar, HelloLib } from "testprivatenprodney/lib/HelloLib";
```

it works as long as the navBar component does not have any child components. If it has I get "Module not found" error again.

[image]

I think I am missing something in my webpack configuration. yet all I can find is to have the resolve array, which is included.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should export your components from `src/index.js`. Currently it does not export anything.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but how would I include the bundle file then? via a require()?